# ESQL XML Creation in IIB

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Can someone help me in creating the below xml structure using ESQL in IIB

Input:

```
<animal>
     <animaldomestic>dog<animaldomestic>
     <animalwild>cheetah<animalwild>
</animal>
```

Output:

```
<animals>
  <animal type="domestic">cow</animal>
  <animal type="wild">cheetah</animal>
</animals>
```

Comment: Sorry steven. I am an novice ESQL developer. I am pretty confused in creating the above structure.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to make a Table called Animals, with entries in it for Lion, and Cheetah that will be easy to do, but you'll need to do. Try looking at the ESQL documentation for creation a Database/Table. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0228.htm

Comment: Thanks for your input steven. But, I am using IIB Middleware where i need to use the ESQL in compute node for transforming the input xml to above xml format.

Answer (score 4):

SET OuputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.(XMLNSC.Attribute)animal = 'domestic'; 
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal = 'cow';

SET OuputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.(XMLNSC.Attribute)animal = 'wild'; 
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal = 'cheetah';

Answer (score 2):

@Egorka_nazarov's solution is the best. A couple of improvements are possible, though:

```
    FOR refAnimals AS InputRoot.XMLNSC.animal.*[];
      CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals 
        AS refNewAnimal
        TYPE NameValue 
        NAME 'animal' 
        VALUE FIELDVALUE(refAnimals);

      DECLARE type CHARACTER SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME(refAnimals) AFTER 'animal');
      SET refNewAnimal.(XMLNSC.Attribute)type = type;
    END FOR;
```

The above code is shorter and less likely to contain bugs (once you have practiced with REFERENCE variables, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this.Please find the below code:

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[1].(XMLNSC.Attribute)type = 'domestic';
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[1]VALUE = InputRoot.XMLNSC.animal.animaldomestic;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[2].(XMLNSC.Attribute)type = 'wild';
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[2]VALUE = InputRoot.XMLNSC.animal.animalwild;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want universal code:

```
DECLARE animal REFERENCE TO InputRoot.XMLNSC.animal.*[>];
DECLARE type CHAR;
DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
WHILE LASTMOVE(animal) DO
    SET type = SUBSTRING(FIELDNAME(animal) AFTER 'animal');
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[I] = FIELDVALUE(animal);
    SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.animals.animal[I].(XMLNSC.Attribute)type = type;
    SET I = I + 1;
    SET type = '';
    MOVE animal NEXTSIBLING; 
END WHILE;
```